# How to check subdomain with string is "us"

Tags: php

I have a sample code to check if the string subdomain is "us"

```
$string = "www.domain.com"; // 1
$string = "domain.com"; // 2
$string = "us.domain.com"; // 3
$string = "www.us.domain.com"; // 4
if (preg_match("/^(?=.{2})[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*$/i", $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])) {
     echo "$string include us";                                        
} else {
     echo "$string not include us";
}
```

But result error, how to fix it

Comment: You don't need regexp to find a substring in a larger string. The request is not clear, anyway.

Comment: Are you sure you just want to check if `us` is in the string somewhere? It would break on domains such as `asus.com`...? Why not use a [specific URL parser for this job?](https://github.com/jeremykendall/php-domain-parser)

Comment: @samiles why include a three-dozen files package for a functionality that can be easily written in 3 lines of code?

Comment: why not change your regex to (\.us.)|(us.)

Comment: @axiac Only thinking if you have lots of urls like `http://us.x.com`, `us.com`, `asus.com`, `x.us`, etc, it's useless to just check if it `us` is present somewhere in the string if you are trying to check it is the subdomain...

Answer (score 0):

If by "subdomain" you mean that the tld and the main domain are excluded, that means we'll have to check for the text "us" and two dots further in the text.

It will also match with sub-subdomains (Like us.subdomain.domain.us)

```
<?php

$domains = [
    'www.domain.us',
    'domain.us',
    'domainuscomputers.com',
    'us.domain.us',
    'www.asuscomputers.usdomain.us',
    'us.subdomain.domain.us',
];

$reg = '/us.*\..*\./';

foreach ($domains as $domain) {
    $match = preg_match($reg, $domain) ? 'subdomain containing "us" found' : 'No match';

    printf('domain %s : %s<br>', $domain, $match);
}
```

Note that the regular expression may be improved, but hey, it works !

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case I don't see the need of using regular expressions.
I think a simple strpos will do the job.
Try this code:

```
$string = "www.domain.com"; // 1
$string = "domain.com"; // 2
$string = "us.domain.com"; // 3
$string = "www.us.domain.com"; // 4


if (strpos($string,'us.')) {
    echo "$string include us";                                        
    } else {
    echo "$string not include us";
}
```